# Print GCC version without license/copyright information

Tags: gcc, version

I'm both writing Makefiles and setting up Docker images for building in a CI environment. In these various scripts I want to print the version of the tools I'm setting up and/or using.

`gcc --version` shows the simple version number *and* some copyright and license information. Example output on my machine:

```sh
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is there a simpler way to get just the version information without parsing this output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's two ideas:

#### 1. Use the `-dumpversion` option instead. It should print a nice, succinct version number. Works on any platform without further parsing.

```sh
$ gcc -dumpversion
8.1.0

$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -dumpversion
8.3.1
```

EDIT 2021-01-17:

I recently discovered that on earlier GCC versions `-dumpversion` only showed the major version, and `-dumpfullversion` printed all Major.Minor.Patch version numbers. So try `-dumpfullversion` if the above doesn't work for you.

#### 2. On Linux (or Bash/MSYS for Windows) you've got `head` to grab the first line

```sh
$ gcc --version | head -n1
gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

$ arm-none-eabi-gcc --version | head -n1
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 8-2019-q3-update) 8.3.1 20190703 (release) [gcc-8-branch revision 273027]
```

Comment: `-dumpversion` was exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't finding it on Google, so I made this Q&A style post here in the hopes that others might find it useful.